# [Xcode][iOS]Question about making cell designed custom in .xib file to fit the entire screen/superview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I tried to make my own custom cell with two labels embedded on a stack view, but no matter what I tried , I can't get the cell to stick to the edged of the superview. I've also tried previously to put the labels directly in the view and use constraints but they don't seem to have any effect. Is there a bug with the UI from .xib files ? Or do you have any idea of what should I be trying ? In the screenshots you have the constraints I've used

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's **very** difficult to tell what's going on from just those two images. Share your XIB file (either via a file sharing service or post the source of it).

Comment: @DonMag  here is the shared file. Thank you ![link]https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kTWawwk3jDSuecILDhFYywIJY0zT6gmk?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

First tip: Give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easier to see their frames.

I set the background colors of your `Category Label` to Cyan, your `Task Title Label` to yellow and your `Is Priority Image View` to red.

The **main** issue is that you set `TaskCell` as the `Custom Class` of the `Content View`.

Some detailed info...

---

Here's what we get using your XIB as-is:

[image]

So, the first issue - looking at your actual XIB... you set `TaskCell` as the `Custom Class` of the cell itself, which is **Correct**:

[image]

but, you're ***also*** setting it on the `ContentView`, which is **Incorrect**:

[image]

Changing the class of the `ContentView` back to the default:

[image]

And we get this:

[image]

That's probably close to what you want, but...

The power of a `UIStackView` is how it lays-out its Arranged Subviews. There *are* occasions where we add constraints to those subviews, but in general you should configure the stack view to arrange the subviews on its own.

If we delete these constraints:

[image]

leaving:

[image]

We get this result:

[image]

This now matches your stack view configuration -- `Distribution: Fill Equally` and `Spacing: 53`.

In addition, you have constrained your stack view to the Content View:

[image]

but, to get automatic default spacing, you may also want to constrain the stack view to the Content View's **Margins**:

[image]

and we get this:

[image]